# How to pull YTD data of the previous N years based on today's date in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to pull a report based out of the `CURRENT_DATE()` and I need this report showing the data of previous N years too.
How should I write query in Postgresql?

Sample table: `User`- `user_id|created_date`
Expected Output: `Year|Count_of_Acquired_Users_YTD`
For example: `2014|100,000 (this is the number of acquired users from 2014-01-01 to current_date of 2014 (2014-11-29)`

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Maybe join with `(SELECT d::date FROM generate_series(current_date - '10 years'::interval, current_date, '1 year') d)`